# How to change the UINavigationVIewController when using presentModalViewController

Tags: objective-c, ipad

How do I set the modalViewControll to a particular size?

```
UINavigationController *NC = (More stuff);

[self presentModelViewController:NC]...;
```

that code presents my UIViewController as a full screen. I want to to be a smaller window size  is that possible or do I need to do a popovercontroller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something other than full screen you can look at setting the `modalPresentationStyle` property on the `UINavigationController` you're about to display.

```
NC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

Look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to see what styles are available.  If you need something different than those styles then you'll have to do it all yourself.  If you use a UIPopoverController you have to be prepared for the user to dismiss your popover by simply tapping elsewhere on the screen.

Comment: This is the way to go if you want to use the three I believe sizes that the iOS SDK provides. If you want to do custom sizes, reimplementing the behaviour of a modal is pretty simple. I've created modal views that are only a couple of hundred pixels tall/wide by drawing what I want on a full page, making the background translucent and drawing a smaller view inside.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [`modalPresentationStyle` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/UserInterface/UserInterface.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH3-SW16) of UIViewController.